# Replace Empty URL Space with %20 for HTML Link

Tags: javascript, arrays, sharepoint, replace, indexof

I have a function that I thought I had working to replace a URL with an HTML link when someone submits something on a form of ours. If the users enters a URL with a space, for example:

`company.sharepoint.com/sites/testsite/shared documents/forms/allitems.aspx`

The function cuts off anything after the space.

Below is my code:

```
ReplaceURLwithHTMLLinks: function(text) {
 if (text !=null && text.length > 0) {
  var exp = /(\b(https?):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|}{\[\]\(\)"'])/i;

  if (text.indexOf("-") > -1) {
   
   var linkText;

   if (text.indexOf("company.sharepoint.com") > -1
    linkText = text.substring(0, text.indexOf('-') - 1) + " - SharePoint";
   else
    linkText = text.substring(0, text.indexOf('-') - 1);

   var newLink = text.replace(exp, "<a target='_blank' rel='noopener noreferrer' href='$1'>" + linkText + "</a>";

   return newLink.substring(newLink.indexOf("<a"));
   }
 }

 else {
  return test;
  }
}
```

I am trying to find out how to replace any blank spaces with a %20 to still allow the HTML Link to load properly

Thanks

Comment: There are built-ins for this: [`encodeURI()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI) and [`encodeURIComponent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent). The differences are covered here: [encodeURI vs encodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI#encodeuri_vs_encodeuricomponent).

Answer (score 1):

You could try this?

```
text.replace(/\s/g, "%20");
```

it replaces all the empty spaces with %20

Comment: The `\s` [character class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Character_Classes#types) matches **all whitespace**, so this will also replace tabs, newlines, etc.

Comment: this wouldn't be an issue for urls that can't contain tabs and newlines.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Notepad++ to replace all the spaces in your href="..." and src="..." tags by using a macro:

1. Start Recording Macro
2. Start search (ctrl/F)
   a. Select Regular Expression
   b. Type exactly href="(.*?)"  or src="(.*?)"
   This will match the next href or src strings in the file
3. Click Find Next.
4. Select replace tab on the search box
   a. **Click "In selection" box**
   b. Set Find to one space
   c. Set Replace to %20
5. Click Replace All
6. Stop recording macro
7. Save and run the macro once at a time or from Macro menu